# Documenting callback typedefs in Doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen, typedef

I have the following typedef:

```
typedef void( __cdecl *tCallback )( const char* Message );
```

How would I document that correctly using Doxygen?

I would like to to have the tCallback documented and the parameters expected documented.

A simple example:

```
/// \typedef test
typedef test bool
```

produces correct output in doxygen

```
//typedef tCallback
typedef void( __cdecl *tCallback )( const char* Message );
```

produces:

```
C:/test.cpp:2: warning: Found ';' while parsing initializer list! (doxygen could be confused by a macro call without semicolon)
C:/test.cpp:1: warning: member with no name found.
```

and

```
//typedef void( __cdecl *tCallback )
typedef void( __cdecl *tCallback )( const char* Message );
```

produces the same as the above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doxygen and typedefs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290406/doxygen-and-typedefs), which suggests that you may need to properly qualify your typedef name if it's inside a namespace or nested within another type

Comment: Not a duplicate as that question asks for simple typedefs not complex ones like this.  The answers there did not help, I searched first.

Comment: Anybody want to tell me why the votes to close?  There is no duplicate here.  The duplicate pointed out above was for simply typedefs in a namespace, the namespace was causing the issue. This question is unrelated.

Comment: @gbrandt this seems like a duplicate of the question @Ben linked. Why would a complex typedef behave any differently? Can you update your question with an example showing it working with a non-function pointer typedef?

Comment: @Sam I have no idea why a complex typedef would behave differently, hence the question.  Edited for clarity

Comment: @gbrandt if you remove __cdecl does the problem reproduce?

Comment: @Sam removing __cdecl stops the errors and produces expected result.  So I should probably file this in the doxygen bug tracker

Comment: @gbrandt: If you've already read other questions, it's a good idea to include links to them.  If `__cdecl` is causing the trouble, you can work around it using the `PREDEFINED` configuration option in your Doxyfile.

Comment: @Ben - why would I include a link to a question that is not relevant to the question I am asking.  Just because that question mentions typedef when the real question is about namespaces, does not make it related to my question.

Comment: @gbrandt: It's part of the "Here's what I have already tried" discussion that is essential to a good question.

Comment: @Ben - I'm going to have to disagree. The question you pointed out was not relevant to my question since namespaces are not involved in my question.  The question you pointed out was badly named as typedefs were a side effect of the namespace issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to your Doxyfile:

```
PREDEFINED = __cdecl=
```

This will cause Doxygen to ignore this identifier for purposes of documentation.

Comment: better is some cases (in mine) was to use 'PREDEFINED = __cdecl :=' so that __cdecl could not be re-assigned.

Comment: A small precision : you need to activate macro expansion (MACRO_EXPANSION = YES) as well, or PREDEFINED won't have any effect.

Comment: However, your docs will then not show the correct callback signature, right? The __cdecl will be not be shown in the docs, which could cause problems (compiler error at the very least) if the user copied the signature from the docs rather than the header. Seems to me that there should be a way to have the docs display the typedef identically as it is in the code.

Comment: @dlchambers: Calling conventions are affected by compiler options, but the docs don't show those either.